# MPI coding practices with large projects multiple MPI_Finalize(); or just one?

Tags: c++, mpi

Hi for large mpi projects in c++ with multiple .hp and .cpp files ,should there be a MPI_Finalize(); at the end of every header or cpp file that uses an mpi function? or should there just be on global one in the main cpp file? This also goes with initiation of MPI as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPI_Init() is in charge of initiating communication with the other processes, so you only want to call that once if possible. MPI_Finalize() means you're done with MPI, and won't be calling any more MPI functions for the rest of the program.

Comment: so just set everything up on the main file? and if a header or cpp files uses some mpi function i would just need to #include "MPI.h"

the reason i ask is i've seen both ways done in pratice

Comment: +1, with a caveat.  MPI_Init() is _not_ in charge of starting the other processes; it's in charge of initializing the library, whatever that may mean for any given implementation.   The standard doesn't say when the other processes are started, but generally it's by mpiexec/mpirun.   You're not allowed to call _any_ other MPI function once you've called MPI_Finalize(), so you only want to call it once.

Comment: -1: `MPI_Init()` most definitely isn't in charge of starting the other processes. Indeed, the other processes are already running by the time `MPI_Init()` is reached. What Init does is initialize the environment so that other MPI calls can be made. Likewise, Finalize signifies that no MPI calls should be allowed from this point, but it does not terminate the other processes.

Comment: see what i mean now i'm confused again thanks @suszterpatt so in other words it doesnt matter if i put mpi_finalize in each header or in just my main file?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that mix up. I was thinking too quick about this. What everyone else said is right - MPI_Init is simply what initializes the communication with all the other processes, and loads things for each one. The answer has been edited to match that.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MPI Reference](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node175.html#SECTION00830000000000000000):

> [MPI_Init] must be called before any other MPI routine. It must be
>   called at most once; subsequent calls are erroneous (see
>   MPI_INITIALIZED).
>
> All MPI programs must contain a call to MPI_INIT; this routine must be
>   called before any other MPI routine (apart from MPI_INITIALIZED) is
>   called.
>
> [...]
>
> [MPI_Finalize] cleans up all MPI state. Once this routine is called, no
>   MPI routine (even MPI_INIT) may be called.